# A Conflict Between Coordinate and Proper Relative Velocities?

Tags: special-relativity, coordinate-systems, velocity

Are we forced to conclude that a muon created in the earth's atmosphere has a coordinate relative velocity that is always $\gamma^2$ greater than its proper relative velocity?

Consider an “average” muon which has formed in a collision 1143 m above the surface of the earth and is traveling straight down (or the earth is traveling straight up) at a proper relative velocity .867 c in the earth’s frame of reference. At the stated relative velocity and distance, this muon’s self-disintegration will coincide with the moment that it strikes the surface of the earth.

Now calculate the muon’s coordinate relative velocity from the earth's frame of reference. We know that at the moment of the muon’s inception, traveling at a proper relative velocity of .867 c and using its Lorentz-contracted co-moving coordinate system, the muon will measure its altitude to be 2286 m above the surface of the earth. We also know that because this muon is an “average” muon, only 2.2 $\mu$secs of coordinate time will have elapsed when the muon disintegrates at the surface of the earth. Dividing the coordinate distance traveled, 2286 m, by the coordinate elapsed time of 2.2 $\mu$secs, gives a coordinate relative velocity of 3.46 c which is equivalent to the proper relative velocity .867 c times $\gamma^2$.

The above also leads to the conclusion that the coordinate relative velocity of a muon or any other object, always exceeds the speed of light when its proper relative velocity is greater than .618 c.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by coordinate and proper relative velocity; it isn't standard terminology. If 1143 m is the muon's initial altitude in the lab frame (Earth rest frame), then the initial altitude in the muon's rest frame is 571.5 m, not 2286 m.

Comment: Yes, 571.5 m is the muon's proper distance in the muon's frame.  But when we look at the muon from the earth's frame, the first thing we notice is that the there are 2 meter marks on the muon's co-moving coordinate system for every 1 meter mark on our stationary earthbound coordinate system due to Lorentz contraction of the muon's co-moving frame.  Remember that we are appraising from the earth frame the *coordinate* distance, and not the muon's proper distance, that we believe the muon *should* measure base on the muon's contracted co-moving coordinate system that we see.  Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

If $1143\text{ m}$ is the muon's initial altitude in the lab frame (Earth rest frame), then the initial altitude in the muon's rest frame is $571.5\text{ m}$, not $2286\text{ m}$. In a comment you wrote:

> [...] from the earth's frame, [...] there are 2 meter marks on the muon's co-moving coordinate system for every 1 meter mark on our stationary earthbound coordinate system due to Lorentz contraction [...]

From this, I think the problem is that you're mixing position and time coordinates from different inertial systems.

Say the earth's rest frame is the unprimed system and the muon's is the primed system. The muon's metersticks tell you $x'$, and there are clocks attached to them that tell you $t'$. But when you counted muon metersticks from the muon to the ground (getting $2286\text{ m}$), you did it at a constant $t$. You need to do it at a constant $t'$.

At the $t$ when the muon is created, the clock near the ground shows an earlier time than the clock near the muon (relativity of simultaneity). The way to measure the distance is to record the $x'$ and $t'$ of the muon when it's created, then wait until the clock nearest the ground reads $t'$, then record that clock's $x'$ and take the difference of the two. The result will be $571.5\text{ m}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Some clarification please. Let's say that t = 0 and x' = 571.5 m at the muon's creation. Then does t' = -1.1 usec, or does t' = -2.2 usec, or does t' = -4.4 usec at the muon's creation?

Comment: @PatDolan I'm not sure exactly what you mean. If the primed clock on the ground reads $t'=0$ at $t=0$, then $t'$ at the muon creation event will be positive. You can work it out from the Lorentz transformation: $t'=γ(t+vx/c^2) = γvx/c^2 \approx 6.6\text{ μs}$. The primed clock near the ground reaches that same time at $t=3.3\text{ μs}$. In that $3.3\text{ μs}$ in the lab frame, the muon moved ¾ of the way to the ground, so it's $x=285.75\text{ m}$ from the ground, but the primed metersticks are contracted, so...